# How do we get Select Invitees widget on VF page?

Tags: visualforce

Can we get the Select Invitees widget(related list not sure what to call it) on a VF page? We can find this on the bottom of the events standard page.

I am trying to create a Vf page to enter event details

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No. You'd have to write the code for that yourself. Many standard elements in the UI are not representable with a single tag in Apex Code, despite their general applicability in custom developments.